# object required error

Tags: javascript

where is error?

```
<iframe  src="jquerytabs/index.html" name="bulten"  scrolling="auto"  id="ifr2" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="7"  height="288" ></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.write(parent.document.getElementById('ifr2').src) --->error is here but how can I correct?
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have an element with id='ifr2' on the page?

Comment: Is it executed from an iFrame?

Comment: what type of object is `ifr2` and what does `parent` refer to? Is it to a parent frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `parent.document.getElementById('ifr2')` is returning `null`.  Why are you using `parent.document` instead of just `document`?

Does your script really come *after* the `<iframe>`, as it does in the code you posted? Is it possible that you have more than one element with the same "id" value ("ifr2") (probably not, but it's worth checking)?

Comment: iframe isn'n loading but iframe is loading when I do refresh in IE

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, @stack5.  The error you're getting doesn't have much to do with whether the `<iframe>` content loads.

Comment: now iframe is loadig with -document.write(parent.document.getElementById('ifr2').src)- but I have object required error

Comment: You should post more of your code, and take the time to provide a complete description of what happens when your page loads and what the problems/errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read the iframe URL or the HTML of the content inside the iframe? Your posted code seems to indicate the former, if the `parent.` part is removed:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.write(document.getElementById('ifr2').src);
</script>
```

Comment: error was correct but Linlk see (http://domainname/anasayfa/jquerytabs/index.html) how can I hide

Comment: The links leads to nowhere. What is it that you want to hide? The iFrame?

Comment: background color=white
I done white to link leads color now link leads not see

Comment: Then you'll need to change the color of the links (using CSS).

Answer (score 0):

I have more than one element with the same "id" value ("ifr2") but  I changed "id" valume.Now no problem :)